# SCOM maintenance mode trigger based on PowerShell script on client

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, automation, sccm, scom

Appreciate any suggestions with this, I am looking to make a scom configuration in such a way that it monitors for a PowerShell script deployed onto a server and puts that server to maintenance mode based on the script's output.

It is ideal if this script is being spooled by the scom config too, so far I have been trying to use notification command channels and appreciate any suggestions please.

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault.  Please update your question and advise what you've already tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Operations Manager Shell which is based on Windows Powershell

[Operations Manager Shell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/operationsmanager/?view=systemcenter-ps-2019)

For scheduling a maintenance mode for any monitored server, you can use

```
New-SCOMMaintenanceSchedule
```